# Use value of LaunchConfiguration in ROS2 launch file like a variable

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to add two strings together, passed as LaunchConfiguration in my launch file.
I have found many answers on that regarding a boolean and to use conditions instead, but is there something simillar to work with the value of the launch description directly in the code? (e.g. use the path to read a file )

EDIT:
I found `IfCondition(PythonExpression(["'", LaunchConfiguration('test'), "' == 'true']))._predicate_func(LaunchContext)).perform(LaunchContext)`
Maybe something simmilar can be used to get the real value.

`launch_ros.parameter_descriptions.ParameterValue(value, value_type=str)` could also be a possible option

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405741/use-value-of-launchconfiguration-in-ros2-launch-file-like-a-variable/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2022-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) on 2022-08-31**:
You need to check opaquefunction for retrieving the value as string and manipulating according to your needs. Seems to be multiple stages in launch. You can read more about it here [#q396345](https://answers.ros.org/question/396345/ros2-launch-file-how-to-convert-launchargument-to-string/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a way to do it :D
Here is an example:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription, LaunchContext
from launch.actions import OpaqueFunction
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def example_func(context: LaunchContext, arg1: LaunchConfiguration):
    value = context.perform_substitution(namespace)
    value +="/miracle/" # you can use it as a python variable now :D
    return Node(name=value)

def generate_launch_description():
    name = LaunchConfiguration('name')
    return LaunchDescription([
        OpaqueFunction(function=example_func, args=[namespace])
    ])
```

Normally, ROS2 will first build the context and afterwards execute everything, so it is not possible to get any value. With the OpaqueFunction() one can delay the execution of code, so that the context exists and the value can be retrieved. ([See documentation](https://design.ros2.org/articles/roslaunch.html))

I hope this example is understandable and can help someone.

---

Originally posted by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/64639/zeckurbo/) with karma: 105 on 2022-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-12**:
Should

```
name = LaunchConfiguration('name')
```

be like this?

```
namespace = LaunchConfiguration('name')
```